# Save pdf inside html5 local storage

Tags: html, local-storage

I am using mozilla pdf.js to read and display content of a pdf file on browser. Later i thought to take this functionality offline and make use of local storage.

Till now i am able to create an offline app which makes use of manifest to make my app offline but the real challenge i have is how to read the pdf which is lying on my server.

Is there any way to save that pdf inside the local storage or any other way to save pdf data as blob inside local storage and then make on fly pdf using blob data.

Kindle cloud reader has this functionality but i am not sure how they are doing it.

Also i am not looking for code ( if any one can show the code that will be great ). Just guide me to the right direction because i know it is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use indexed DB. 
http://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/02/storing-images-and-files-in-indexeddb/

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh779017%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Also work on your accept rate..seems too low..

Comment: Links seems to be helpful, will read them. Thanks Rajesh and wish u happy new year